# I want to convert ebxml to xml and vica versa in JAVA

Tags: java, xml, ebxml

I am trying to convert ebxml to xml and vica versa so that my downstream system can communicate with Jentrata. Any help on this will be appericiated.

Thanks
Kind Regards
Sumanpreet Singh

Comment: Hello and welcome on StackOverflow!!! In order to get your a better answer, and your answer don't get deleted later on, you would have to read and follow some basic rules and conventions that will help everyone to communicate and help better. Please go to https://stackoverflow.com/help and read about the topic "What topics can I ask about here?", and "What types of questions should I avoid asking?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality is part of jentrata and can be found in controller class. it uses and callback url to send the file to downstream systems, where you can write the code to handle the payload.